# Run a shell command in Python

Tags: shell, python, aws

Environment - PyCharm

I am using the below command to get the JSON file:-

```
aws rds describe-db-cluster-snapshots > snapshotdetails.json
```

I am using this Json file to extract some data. I want the above command to run from my Python script. I have tried below but its failing:-

```
from subprocess import call
call(["aws rds describe-db-cluster-snapshots > snapshotdetails.json"])
```

I am getting error and its not working. Any pointers??

Error:-

```
Traceback (most recent call last):File "/Users/PrashastKumar/Desktop/CrossRegion/venv/lib/crossregiontrial.py", line 3, in <module>
call(["aws rds describe-db-cluster-snapshots > snapshotdetails.txt"])
File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 522, in call
return Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs).wait()
File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 710, in __init__
errread, errwrite)
File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 1335, in _execute_child
raise child_exception
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

Comment: Not without seeing the error.

Comment: @JohnMiliter: you mean to say i need to use below

Comment: call(["aws", "rds", "describe-db-cluster-snapshots" > snapshotdetails.txt"])

Comment: call(["aws", "rds", "describe-db-cluster-snapshots",  ">snapshotdetails.txt"]) -- used this , but getting error "Unknown options: >snapshotdetails.txt"

Comment: `">", "snapshotdetails.txt"` ?

Comment: still same error Unknown options: snapshotdetails.txt, >

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/89228/calling-an-external-command-in-python

Comment: [How do I pipe a subprocess call to a text file?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4856684/4440445) (note: the user says "pipe" but it's really about output redirection to a file)

Comment: `call([...], shell=True)` for advanced shell operations like pipes and redirects

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `python3` solution:

```
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE
cmd_output = Popen(["echo", "foo"], stdout=PIPE)
with open('bar.txt', 'w') as out_handle:
    out_handle.write(cmd_output.communicate()[0].decode('UTF-8'))
```